# Why this piece of code might produce large negative value?

Tags: javascript, math, analytics

I'm using a simple JavaScript to figure out the the average time spent on a page. It works fine, but sometimes it produces a really large negative value such as this. `-686496480000`

Here's the code.

```
module.exports = function(options) {
  var _lastHeartbeat = (new Date()).getTime();
  var _specialEvents = {
    heartbeat: function (e) {
      var heartbeat = (new Date()).getTime();

      _queueEvent({}, {
        _t: 'timespent',
        _v: Math.round((heartbeat - _lastHeartbeat) / 1000) * 1000
      });

      _sendEvents();

      _lastHeartbeat = heartbeat;
    }
  }

  var _startHeartbeat = function () {

    var beat = function (interval) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        _specialEvents.heartbeat();
        if (interval < _config.heartbeat.max) {
          beat(_config.heartbeat.degrade(interval));
        }
      }, interval);
    };

    beat(_config.heartbeat.start);
  }

  var _init = function (ops) {
    _startHeartbeat();
  }

  return {init: _init};
};
```

And this is the from config

```
  heartbeat: {
    start: 5000,
    max: 600000,
    degrade: function (interval) {
      var int = Math.pow(interval, 1.05);
      return Math.round(int/10000) * 10000;
    }
  }
```

The code might not be complete but that's the second of the code where it's getting the last timestamp and subtract that with `now` timestamps then fire the request. So, I can calculate the average how long a user has spent on a page.

For regular case, the request will be fired like this.

```
_t=timespent,_v=5000
_t=timespent,_v=10000
_t=timespent,_v=20000
_t=timespent,_v=30000
_t=timespent,_v=50000
```

But sometimes, the `_v` value will `-686496480000` or something really large. I can't seem to figure out where the math would be wrong.

Comment: What's `_queueEvent()`?

Comment: Probably not the source of the error, but I find a bit confusing that you have a variable named `heartbeat` inside a function assigned to property `heartbeat`

Comment: What are the values of `heartbeat` and `_lastHeartbeat` when this happens?

Comment: It would be the timestamp. For example, 1459812158554

Comment: Oh you mean when the value is big negative number? I couldn't find the source of the problem yet. I thought I did something wrong with the math.

Comment: Instead of `(new Date()).getTime()` consider `Date.now()` or `+new Date()`. As Barmar says, log the values of other variables when that occurs, e.g. `if (_v < 0) /* log stuff */`

Comment: Can you explain what's the difference between (new Date()).getTime() and Date.now() or new Date()?

Comment: _queueEvent is just where we send the event by placing a pixel on the page.

Comment: what environment is the script running on?

Comment: It's running on all the browsers.